# Is it possible to create a self contained Angularjs app that will not clash with with any other Js or css libraries on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, angularjs

This may not be a plausible and I will except that as an answer if someone can tell me why with reasonable detail but I am looking to create a simple Angularjs app that I can include in any html page (whether on a tomcat server, MAMP or in wordpress) and it not be affected by any js/css libraries used on the same page except by my app's own Dependencies.

For example, if I built a simple Calculator that uses a specific version of Bootstrap, Jquery and Angularjs, I would like to be able to give someone the project folder and a simple snippet or 2 like the following and it would work on their site without clashing with anything else already existing on their site.

```
<div data-my-ng-calculator></div>
```

I realise that it if this is plausible may require some complex angular application bootstrapping or even an external library to some how load my JS and CSS in some sort of self contained container. Or maybe inside my app I need to find some way to reference my libraries and Css class with a custom selector of some sort????

Any advice or links to articles/tutorial/frameworks or books on the matter would be welcomed. Obviously this is currently hypothetical ( or maybe it's not and someone has seen similar already) and I am just looking to explore the possibility

I have tried Googling this but so far i haven't been able to find anything but this is probably down to bad search terms.

Comment: What you are looking for is the (emerging) [web components](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/) standard. That said, I don't think this question is a good fit for SO.

Comment: @steveax thanks and excuse my ignorance but why is SO not a good fit for this question and where would be so I know for future reference

Comment: Seems like it could work just as well to create a module with your directive in it, and let people just include it in their project. You could package it with bower for example, and be able to independently express your module's dependencies.

Comment: @aet that would only sandbox it from other Angular modules would it not? I am talking about sandboxing any JS Library and CSS framework. so you could then on the same page have different versions jquery bootstrap (including different bootstrap themes) and etc. I believe steveax hit the nail on the head but just not available as standard yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is an emerging standard called Web Components (Thanks @steveax for pointing me to this). From here I was able to then find this excellent tutorial on [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/modular-future-web-components/) , in particular the section on the Shadow Dom was very relevant. unfortunately according to [canIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/shadowdom) it is only supported in Chrome and and Opera at the moment.